# Does cider need yeast nutrient?

Tags: yeast, cider, yeast-nutrient

From what I've read, beer wort is relatively rich in nutrients and mead must is nutrient-poor.  **Where does cider fit on this spectrum?**

I typically do small batches and pitch pretty generously, one dry yeast packet split between two one-gallon batches.  I always use some adjunct sugars, either brown sugar, juice concentrate, or honey.

I'm hoping to get a batch started this weekend - do you think it would benefit from some nutrient?  Would something like Mangrove Jack's M02 that claims to have nutrient in it suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really depends on the apple juice which depends on the soil the trees are grown.

I've done size-by-side tests on 1 gallon batches with and without 1/4 tsp each of yeast nutrients (DAP, ammonium sulfate) & 'energizer' using commercial filtered apple juice. Using 1g Lalvin EC-1118 in each, they both fermented fine in the same time and the taste was indistinguishable. I wouldn't be surprised if the commercial orchards are well fed resulting in a juice with good nutrients. However I do seem to recall some fermentations I've tried with local wild juices being sluggish without nutrients.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, cider needs a lot of nutrients for healthy yeast growth.

Here's a couple ways to get around adding nutrients.

**Full pitch of yeast.** This basically skips a growth phase be case all the needed yeast is there. Usually done by racking juice on top of your last batches yeast trub.

**Malted Cider** in a 50/50 blend wort/Apple juice. This will give yeast all the nutrients it needs. Also the residual unfermentable sugars in the wort, usually eliminate the need to backsweeten.

Comment: Thanks EvilZ!  Great idea with the malted cider, I’ll have to try that.